# Imbalanced dataset for recommender system

Tags: python-3.x, keras, recommendation-engine, rating

I am building a recommender system with keras. The training set has more than 200K samples but 180K are from rating 4. The distribution is given here.

Rating
5.0        89
4.0    187836
3.0     20032
2.0      6185
1.0       648
0.0        36
dtype: int64

Obviously the model fails for less represented labels. How do I solve this?

I have tried SMOTE but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sklearn to compute the [class weight](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.class_weight.compute_class_weight.html). And use those calculated parameters to assign `class_weight` in `model.fit`. This might help to tackle your issue.

Answer (score 0):

A simple oversampling method might help. You can try this [balanced batch generator](https://github.com/soroushj/keras-balanced-batch-generator) for Keras. It generates *balanced batches*, i.e., batches in which the number of samples from each class is on average the same. This can prevent the model from getting biased towards the majority class. Also, I recommend a small batch size, e.g., 32 or 64.